# What would be the result of window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language if I run it on browser in Romania

Tags: javascript, culture

What would be the result of running `window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language` - in a browser in Romania? Is it 'ro' or something else?

PS: I work on a restricted environment (not have enough permissions to install a VM).

Comment: google suggests you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome it´s 'ro'. You can add it to your browsers languages in settings and then get the whole list with `navigator.languages`. That´s how you can find out, without changing your overall browser language.